# Some columns became NaN after scaling

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-scaling

I'm trying to scale features with such a function

```
def featureNormalize(X):
'''
This function takes the features as input and
returns the normalized values, the mean, as well 
as the standard deviation for each feature.
'''
X_norm = (X - np.mean(X))/np.std(X)
mu = np.mean(X)
sigma = np.std(X)
return X_norm, mu, sigma
```

and then call it

```
X, mean, std = featureNormalize(X) ## We call the function over the features
```

| Train Set | Test Set |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

So that it works ok for my train set.

But when I call it for a test set], some columns completely turn into Nan
Both sets have no Nan or null values.
I've tried to rewrite this function with `nanmean` and `nanstd`, but it didn't work :

```
def featureNormalize(X):
    X_norm = (X - np.nanmean(X, dtype = 'float32')) / np.nanstd(X, dtype = 'float32')
    mu = np.nanmean(X, dtype = 'float32')
    sigma = np.nanstd(X, dtype = 'float32')
    return X_norm, mu, sigma
```

What can cause this problem and what should I do

Comment: hm, it's not a good idea to normalize train and test sets separately. Test set should be scaled according to train set's std/mean.

Comment: So instead of calling the function a second time I used variables from the first invoke `test_x = (test_x - mean) / std`, but it drops another error ** "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'float'"**